# Compare 2 sets of numbers by Ratio of Geometric means rather than Student t-test

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, geometric-mean

In a medical [article published today](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1816897)(!), ratio of geometric means and its confidence interval is used to compare 2 independent groups rather than Student t-test.

My specific questions are:

1. What are the advantages of such an approach and when it should be used in place of Student t-test.
2. Also, how does one calculate confidence interval of ratio of 2 geometric means?

Thanks for you insight.

Edit: Full reference of above article is: 
`Lemke et al, "Coronary Angiography after Cardiac Arrest without ST-Segment Elevation",

N Engl J Med. 2019 Apr 11;380(15):1397-1407.

doi: 10.1056/NEJMoa1816897`

Also, data is considered `non-parametric` in this article.

The authors have used ratio of geometric means and confidence interval of this ratio as `effect size`.

Comment: Please include a complete reference and more context (it doesn't do to rely on a link -- not least in case the link goes away and in any case the article is gated so it's hard to get details); in particular you don't identify whether this is a test with a parametric assumption or a nonparametric test; hopefully the paper gives some clue about what was done (or the question would be difficult to answer)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these issues. I have clarified these points in the edit of my question above.

Comment: I have edited to give a more complete reference (author, title). Data are of course neither parametric nor nonparametric, but if they think that it is, it might perhaps be a clue to what they might have done -- but hopefully they did more than mischaracterize the data as far as clues about their choice of procedure. Did they mention transforming the variable, for example? This is still remarkably little to go on.

Comment: They have used ratio of geometric means and confidence interval of this ratio as 'effect size'.

Comment: That much is clear from the abstract. It doesn't tell us what assumptions they used. They might, for example, have used a permutation test and associated interval, but they might have taken logs and assumed normality. Or any of a number of other things...

Comment: I am looking for some information on when and how to use ratio of geometric means and confidence intervals of this ratio to compare 2 groups. I am not particularly interested in statistical details of this article. Looking forward to another great answer from you !

Comment: I won't be giving one on present information; it looks to me like the question should be put on hold as unclear (but I am holding off; it's possible that a small edit might be sufficient)

Comment: @Glen_b Has already indicated a general answer: for positive data, a test based on geometric means is equivalent to a test based on the means of the logarithms.